# No se puede crear una base de datos con peewee

Tags: python, mariadb

Bueno estaba viendo un ejemplo de creacion de bases de datos con peewee en python, para ello esty usando mariaDB y usando peewee en python. Ya tengo creado una base de datos vacia llamada usuarios en MariaDB y ahora lo que quiero es poder ejecutar una clase que pueda generarme una tabla dentro de mi base de datos, pero me arroja un error.

```
database = peewee.MySQLDatabase('usuarios', host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', 
passwd='abc')
class User(peewee.Model):
    username = peewee.CharField(unique=True)
    email = peewee.CharField(index = True)
    created_date = peewee.DateTimeField(deafault=datetime.datetime.now)
class Meta:
    database = database
    db_table = 'Users'
if __name__=='__main__':
User.create_table()
```

Y el error que me arroja es:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "f:/DATA_SCIENCE/M2/Clase 02/ORM.py", line 17, in 
class User(peewee.Model):
File "f:/DATA_SCIENCE/M2/Clase 02/ORM.py", line 20, in User
created_date = peewee.DateTimeField(deafault=datetime.datetime.now)
File "C:\Users\GIGABYTE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-
32\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 5009, in **init**
super(_BaseFormattedField, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deafault'

Comment: Escribistes "deafault" en vez de "default" en la línea `created_date = peewee.DateTimeField(deafault=datetime.datetime.now)`

Comment: Bueno ya corregi... ahora me aparece :  MySQL driver not installed!... tengo un motor de bases de datos MariaDB... entonces como lo haria

Comment: Esa sería otra pregunta. Elimina esta y haz una nueva pregunta con el código y el mensaje de error nuevo.

Comment: muchas gracias Candid Moe ya lo pude solucionar eliminando peewee de mis bibliotecas y mas bien adjuntando sqlalchemy...

Comment: Los ORM parecen geniales hasta que empiezas a toparte con situaciones que no pueden manejar adecuadamente. SQL, por otra parte, siempre funciona.